# Customer Attribute not showing in adminhtml customer account form in Magento Enterprise 2.2.0

Tags: adminhtml, customer-attribute, magento-enterprise-2

I have created module "Wgac_Subscription". I want to create custom customer attribute. It is listed in admin as shown in below image, but does not show in customer adminhtml form.

**Wgac/Subscription/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Wgac\Subscription\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;



    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;

    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    /*
        **
        * Create  Customer Attribute "customer_chargify_id"
        ** ==== START ====
        */

         /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_chargify_id', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Chargify Id',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            "unique"  => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' =>999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_chargify_id')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],//you can use other forms also ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        ]);

        $attribute->save();

        /*        
        *   === END ===       
        */



    }
}
```

**Wgac/Subscription/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_con
figuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="customer_chargify_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement"
                    xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source"
                    xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

Kindly suggest me if I am missing something.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can't figure out what is causing this. Were you able to solve it and display the attribute on the customer account in admin?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231216/customer-custom-attribute-not-showing-in-admin-form solved it for me!

Answer (score 4):

The value of 'used_in_forms' should be **['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit']**. If you don't want this attribute to show for a customer, you should set **visible=false**. You can update your InstallData like below:

```
$customerSetup->removeAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_chargify_id');
$customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_chargify_id', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Customer Chargify Id',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => false,
            "unique" => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_chargify_id')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit'],
            ]);
```

And make sure you have deleted YourVendor_YourModule in the **setup_module** table if you want to re-run InstallData script

Hope this will help you

Regards

Comment: One correction: In order for an attribute to be visible to admins but not on the frontend, you need `customer_eav_attribute.is_visible=1` (`visible` true) but `eav_attribute.is_user_defined=0` (`user_defined` false).