# Customer custom attribute not showing in admin form

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-attributes, customer-attribute

I successfully add customer custom attribute for magento 2.2.5 like this:

```
$setup->startSetup();

$insertArray = array(
            'profile_picture' => array("type" => "varchar", "label" => "Profile Picture"),
            'security_question_1' => array("type" => "int", "label" => "Security Question 1"),
            'security_question_2' => array("type" => "int", "label" => "Security Question 2"),
            'security_answer_1' => array("type" => "varchar", "label" => "Security Answer 1"),
            'security_answer_2' => array("type" => "varchar", "label" => "Security Answer 2")
          );

          foreach ($insertArray as $key => $data) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
            $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

            /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
            $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
            $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

            $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $key, [
                'type' => $data['type'],
                'label' => $data['label'],
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 1000,
                'position' => 1000,
                'system' => 0,
            ]);

            $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $key)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

            $attribute->save();
          }
            $setup->endSetup();
```

I can retrieve and set the value programmatically, but the problem is when i edit customer in backend and go to account information tab, it doesn't load the input field for my custom attribute? if there is something missing, how can i update the customer custom attribute?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In contrast to Magento 1, in Magento 2 you now need to add some XML to make custom attributes appear in the edit customer section of the admin.

Create `YourNamespace/YourModule/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml` and add this (at a minimum):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="{{YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE}}" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Replace `{{YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE}}` with the attribute code from your upgrade script.

Run `php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then you're good to go.

Comment: how to add select yes/no input field?

Comment: That's really a new question. Ask that as a new question and I'll answer it. There's not enough room to explain here

Comment: @ProcessEight thank you Sir! You saved my life! beer++

Comment: @TinyDancer in my case I needed a multiselect so I've set it like this: ```formElement="multiselect"```

Comment: I don't think you need to add field to form manually in xml. As of magento 2.3.1 everything working for me with that approach https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277271/23264

Answer (score 1):

ProcessEight answer is not working for us. The field now is visible if u set 'user_defined' to true, but it cannot be saved in backend as well. After reloading customer in backend the field is empty...