# Custom Customer attribute not saving Magento 2.3.1

Tags: attributes, customer, customer-attribute, eav, magento2.3.1

I have the following code to create a custom customer attribute.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\Patch\Data\UpdateIdentifierCustomerAttributesVisibility;

class AddCustomerAccountCode implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_account_code', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Account Code',
            'input' => 'text',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'position' => 100,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            UpdateIdentifierCustomerAttributesVisibility::class,
        ];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

The custom attribute is added to the admin form however when I populate the field and save the customer, the data is not saved.

Please could someone point out where I have gone wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable this attribute for admin form:

```
public function apply()
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_account_code', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Account Code',
            'input' => 'text',
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'position' => 100,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false
        ]);
        $customerAccountCode =$customerSetup->getEavConfig()->clear()
            ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'customer_account_code');


        if ($customerAccountCode->getAttributeId()) {
            $usedInForms =  ['adminhtml_customer','customer_account_create'];
            $data = [];
            foreach ($usedInForms as $formCode) {
                $data[] = ['form_code' => $formCode, 'attribute_id' => $customerAccountCode->getAttributeId()];
            }
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->insertMultiple(
                $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('customer_form_attribute'),
                $data
            );
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }
```

**After that, you need to  cache flush and indexing.**

Comment: Thanks!!! The docs don't mention that https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html

Comment: the docs are bad

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a user_defined equal to true Param to your addAttribute call

'user_defined' => true,

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to this documentation did the trick for me (Magento 2.4):
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/admin/custom-text-field-attribute/

The part about making the attribute available to the admin forms seems to have changed.